# Selenium Python How to check if class AND style match for Element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I have this progress Bar element, as soon as I upload an image the width of the element changes from 0% to 100%

[This is the Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tkri.png)

now what I want to do is **wait until that element is 100%** before doing the next steps in my Python Selenium script. Mainly I want to know if I can just do something like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bar'] [ADD HERE SOMETHING THAT'S LIKE: STYLE WIDTH==100%")))
```

Anything possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bar'][contains(@style,'width: 100%')]
```

Comment: worked perfectly!